# Allowing only superuser to call template column - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have developed a template column using Django tables but i want that only super users should be able to view that column.

MyTables.py

```
class DeviceTable(tables.Table):
    def view(request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            edit = tables.TemplateColumn(template_code)

    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-hover"}
        model = Devices
        fields = (
            "name",
            "location",
            "phone_number",
            "ip_address",
            "created_date",

        )
```

The above code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use [**`before_render`**](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.tables.Table.before_render) hook in this case:

```
class DeviceTable(tables.Table):
    edit = tables.TemplateColumn(template_code)

    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-hover"}
        model = Devices
        fields = (
            "name",
            "location",
            "phone_number",
            "ip_address",
            "created_date",

        )

    def before_render(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.columns.show('edit')
        else:
            self.columns.hide('edit')
```